# Why is the sum of resistances different?

Tags: voltage, parallel

For the following circuit,

[image]

I found the total resistance with the following equation:

[image]

However, the solution calculated the resistances in the left and right portion of the circuit in summation with the middle resistance:

[image]

Why is the resistance added this way, rather than my version?

Comment: Because if you redraw the circuit then you will see the RL and RR are in parallel and then in series with RMid.

Comment: Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and "Save and Insert" on the editor an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slide R<sub>left</sub> across to the far right of the schematic. Now notice that R<sub>left</sub> and R<sub>right</sub> are in parallel. Do the maths on those and convert them to one resistor and redraw the circuit.

The answer should now be fairly obvious.

It should also now be obvious that R<sub>mid</sub> is not in parallel with R<sub>right</sub> as both ends are not directly connected together.